# Make "keeps" the old modification-time, although it has changed

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

***Given a makefile:***

```make
# Create the following sequence of files, in the following order: 1)'old' then 2)'all', finally 3)'new'.
$(shell touch 'old')
$(shell sleep 1)
$(shell touch 'all')
$(shell sleep 1)
$(shell touch 'new')

all: new
    echo '$@'

# Let the modification-time of 'new', to be like 'old' ("older" than 'all').
new :  phony
    cp -p old new

.PHONY : phony

.INTERMEDIATE: new
```

***Running, we get:***

```console
$ make -Wnew
cp -p old new
echo 'all'
all
rm new
```

Now, although `all` ***was*** older than the file `new` ***before*** parsing the build, things changed after Make finished building the `new` file, with the recipe `cp -p old new`, which basically copied the modification-time of `old` into `new`, hence: `all` is ***now*** "newer" than the file `new`.

Then, why does build the up-to-date file `all`, given, that running through its dependencies - ***after*** their respective build - we find that `all` modification-time is "after" that of its dependency "new".

Answer (score 0):

## Explanation of Effect of `-Wnew`

The `-Wnew` option tells `make` to assume that `new` has been modified and that we **must** update the **targets** of which **it is** a **prerequisite**. **Regardless** of what happens to the file `new` in our `makefile` `make` **must update** all of the **targets** `new` is a **prerequisite** of.

I have provided an explanation and demonstration, using your example, that `make` **does not keep** the **old modification time** but that it is the **effect** of the **`-Wnew` option** which causes `make` to rebuild `all`, below.

---

## Process of Execution with `-Wnew`

So in executing `make -Wnew` `make` first reads your `makefile` and sees

```make
all: new
    echo '$@'
```

so it knows regardless of what happens to `new` later on it has to update the target `all` because we've specified the `-Wnew` option.

`make` then proceeds to execute your shell commands and creates the files `old`, `all` and `new`. It now traverses through your targets and prerequisites noting that `phony` does not exist so we must remake it. After making `phony` we then make `new` as its target `phony` is newer than it. This actually modifies `new`'s modification time to be older than `all`. However, we specified `-Wnew` so regardless of what happened to `new` we've told `make` we want it to rebuild targets that have `new` as a prerequisite such as `all`. This is why `make` then proceeds to build `all`.

---

## Demonstration That `make` Does Not Keep Old Modification Times

If we were to execute your example with `make`, (**note** no `-Wnew` option), the output would be

```console
$ make
cp -p old new
```

Aha! `make` didn't update `all`. It realised that by remaking `new` the modification time of `new` changed and it is now older than `all` thus `all` is up to date and we can finish.